# Is there a way to stop enemies from boarding?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

While traveling through space I often find myself batteling enemy ships with teleporters in them. Now right at the start of battle they will usually send a boarding party. Is there a way to stop the teleporter before they send enemies to my ship? Because when my weapons are powered up they are already on board.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I counter enemy away teams?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84470/how-can-i-counter-enemy-away-teams)

Comment: It certainly looks a lot like it. The answer of that question does seem to focus more on repelling the boarders. While I looked at the problem more to see if you can prevent them from boarding at all.

Comment: @yx. I know i've seen that question and awnser, it awnsers how to deal with them when they are on board. But if i have not that much crew on my ship I prefer stopping them from boarding in the first place.

Comment: @Colonel Don't edit other people's questions to add your own.  Please make a new question using the Ask Question button.

Comment: Huh, and to think I'm usually *happy* when the enemy boards my ship - they've split their forces in half, so my whole crew can kill the boarders and then **my** boarding crew is more evenly matched.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is [an augmentation "Weapon Pre-Igniter"](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Weapon_Pre-Igniter) that powers your weapons instantly when you come out of the jump. But even with this it is very hard to stop the teleporter. You need to either have sufficient firepower to bring down the shield and teleport station in one go. Or have enough shield bypassing or enough EMP firepower to be able to bring down the teleport station.

You also need to keep it down the whole battle, if it is repaired for a short time it will probably instantly teleport boarders on board. (This I think, I have not tested this).

When I had a ship with the Weapon Pre-Igniter, I never was able to stop the teleporter quick enough to prevent boarding from taking place. I have not tested this very extensively btw.

Taking out the teleport pad does prevent them from returning to their own ship, a blessing and a curse. (They do not teleport away before you can get the EXP. But on the other hand, you still have boarders on your ship)

The enemy can't teleport to a cloaked ship or retreat their troops from a cloaked ship. So you can use [Stealth Weapons augmentation](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Stealth_Weapons) and cloaking to blast away the teleport pads of the enemy ship.

And, the [Zoltan Shield](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Zoltan_Shield) also prevents ships from teleporting boarders on board. (Events still work).

Comment: The enemy can't teleport to a cloacked ship or retreat their troops from a cloacked ship. If their ship is cloacked, they can still use the teleporter just fine. The same rules apply to the player ship.

Comment: Note that the Stealth ship has built-in Stealth Weapons without using an augmentation slot, so it's relatively effective against boarding attempts right from the start.

Comment: On rebel (or is it federation?) ships, depending on the crew's starting positions, an ion bomb (with the pre-igniter) may be able to neutralize the teleporter before the crew can reach it, it happened to me today. For the smaller mantis ships, though, I think there is no way to disable it in time without cloaking.

Comment: I believe you can also hack the teleporter system on the enemy ship.  Although you'll probably need the Zoltan shield or cloak along with it to buy you enough time to completely prevent boarders.  There's also a super shield drone as another option.

Answer (score 2):

**Cloak** to prevent the cloak from targeting your ship.

**Weapon pre-igniter** to break their teleporter in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip.  Weapon Pre-Igniter works wonders with Ion Bombs.  Since Ion Bombs can bypass shields (besides Voltan), you can easily set an Ion Bomb to disable a Teleporter for 4 clock cycles, buying your ship time to prepare.

Answer (score -5):

Upgrade your doors. It won't prevent boarding but it will definitely slow down the enemies as they have to break down each door before moving between rooms. It's an easy upgrade at the beginning of the game before you can get the more advanced items.