# How to avoid being invaded by enemy in my ship?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to stop enemies from boarding?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85577/is-there-a-way-to-stop-enemies-from-boarding)

Is there a way to avoid enemies intruders in my ship from invading it? If so, which upgraded helps that ?

Comment: We could, at the very least, have posted the link to the qs of which this is a duplicate, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully blocked a teleportation before with the use of two Ion Blasts combined with the Weapon Pre-igniter augmentation. Pause as soon as the fight begins, then direct both Ion Blasts at the teleporters. The first Ion Blast disables the shields, while the second disables the teleporter system.

Comment: Another method is start your cloaking device as soon as you see them about to leave their ship. Meanwhile your weapons will charge up. Direct everything you have at their tele system.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to stop intruders. If you're lucky you can disable their teleporter before they teleport.